# 403 Forbidden Error When Editing a Form - Javascript and Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to use a form to edit a previous post on my site. After clicking edit, using Javascript, I'd like this to happen without requiring a reload of the page.

I'm using Django and trying to use fetch in the Javascript file but I'm pretty lost as to why it's not working. I've been having a lot of trouble with saving things to the database, but also using Javascript at the same time. Any help is appreciated.

When I click edit and try to save, I get 403 forbidden error.

relevant urls.py - I tried this with edit_post/ and it still didn't work:

```
path('edit_post', views.edit_post),
```

javascript:

```
edit = document.querySelectorAll(".edit");
edit.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    edit_handeler(element);
  });
});

function edit_post(id, text) {
form = new FormData();

form.append("id", id);
form.append("text", text.trim());

  fetch("edit_post", {
    method: "POST",
    body: form,
  }).then((res) => {

    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).textContent = text;     
    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value = text.trim(); 
});
}

function edit_handeler(element) {
  id = element.getAttribute("data-id");
  edit_btn = document.querySelector(`#edit-btn-${id}`);

  if (edit_btn.textContent == "Edit") {
 
    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = "block";

    edit_btn.textContent = "Save"; 
    edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-success edit");

      } else if (edit_btn.textContent == "Save") {
     edit_post(id, document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value); //here

    edit_btn.textContent = "Edit";
    edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-primary edit");
  }
}
```

views.py

```
def edit_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_id = request.POST.get('id')
        new_post = request.POST.get('text')
        try:
            # somewhere here is not working
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            if post.user == request.user:
                post.text = new_post.strip()
                #tried newpost.save() did not work
                post.save()
                return JsonResponse({}, status=201)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({}, status=404)

    return JsonResponse({}, status=400)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='author', 
        null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)      
    like = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,  blank=True, related_name="liked_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.username #used to be .user.username
```

Comment: You need to pass the `csrf_token` along with the form data. Otherwise, you want to decorate the view with a `@csrf_exempt` decorator if you think that outside applications can also send POST requests to that view.

Answer (score 0):

A very common error is forgetting about the **Cross Site Request Forgery protection** which is active by default in Django, most probably this is causing the 403 error, so you have some options:

**Option 1:**
Remove the CSRF protection, you can do this by removing `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` from your **MIDDLEWARE** settings, easy but not recommended.

**Option 2:**
Another easy solution is to remove CSRF protection just for the specific view, for example:

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def edit_post(request):
    ...
```

better, but still not recommended.

**Option 3:**
Send the CSRF token to pass the protection, by default the CSRF token will be exposed through the `csrftoken` cookie and the ajax request should send it as a header called `X-CSRFToken`, for example:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookie = {};
    document.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(el) {
        let [k,v] = el.split('=');
        cookie[k.trim()] = v;
    })
    return cookie[name];
}

const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

fetch("edit_post", {
    method: "POST",
    body: form,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    },
}).then((res) => {
    ...
```

Comment: thank you! I did the csrf exempt decorator, and I also took out the django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware from the settings.py file. However, the 403 error goes away. But I noticed the edits I make are not saving to the database. Did you notice anything wrong in my views.py file? I've been playing around with it but not sure why it's not saving to the database.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a condition `post.user == request.user`, according to your models, it should be `post.username == request.user`, this problem is hidden because of your blind try...except.